# Is there a way to prevent download of video in HTML5 video player

Tags: video, download, html5-video

I want to prevent the download of video through right click, developer tools, and browser extensions. Is there a way to achieve this?

A lot of websites already do this but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the 'context menu' on any HTML5 element but you should be aware that this is a fairly simply barrier for someone to work around if they really want to download your video.

Information on disabling the context menu is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

The example, modified for video, looks like this:

```js
noContext = document.getElementById('noContextVideo');

noContext.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<p>The context menu has been disabled on this video.</p>

<video id="noContextVideo" width="320" autoplay controls height="240">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p>But it has not been disabled on this one.</p>

<video width="320" autoplay controls height="240">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Ultimately, if your browser is able to play a video then it is possible for someone to download it using some basic programming or commonly available tools.

The usual approach to address this is to encrypt the video and to share the encryption key securely, either privately somehow or using a DRM system.

Even then, you need to assess the content you are trying to protect - if it is a company internal video with commercial 'secrets' for example, pointing a camera at the screen will copy it with sufficient quality to easily 'leak' those secrets.

Answer (score 0):

As the first poster noted -  it is tough to stop people from downloading your video.  You can also turn off the "download" button in HTML5:

controlslist="nodownload"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList